# wamp phpinfo shows sqlsrv but phpinfo inside artisan server not showing sqlsrv drivers

Tags: sql-server, pdo, laravel-5

I am using Apache 2.4.23 and Php 7.0.10 and Laravel 5.4.
I have installed sqlsrv and it's pdo file inside 'C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10' directory.
So when I created and test.php file in the www directory and executed it I got the following info.

The PDO Information
[image]

the SQLSRV info:

[image]

But when I start php artisan serve and execute phpinfo() then I didn't get the SQL drivers.

PDO extensions:

[image]

Drives SQL

[image]

So when I try to connect to SQL db I am getting this error.

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 647:
```

could not find driver (SQL: SELECT TOP 5 ......

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

WAMPServer has 2 php.ini files. If you want to add the SQLServer extension for use from the command line CLI then you must manually edit the

```
c:\wamp\bin\php\php7.0.10\php.ini
```

and add the new `extension` line

The extension dll's should be placed in the

```
c:\wamp\bin\php\php7.0.10\ext
```

folder.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But to install from CLI.

Comment: Extensions are there in the ext folder 'c:\wamp\bin\php\php7.0.10\ext' and php.ini is already updated.

Comment: BOTH `php.ini` files?

Comment: C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\bin\phi.ini, but this is a link file and it contains the exyensions.
C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10\php.ini, here the ectensions entry are there.

Comment: Like I said in my answer THERE ARE 2. Add the extension into the file I mentioned in my answer. THAT is the ini file user by the PHP CLI